# Data type for blocks in DES-like algorithm in Java

Tags: java, encryption, data-structures, des

I am writing a DES-like block cipher in Java. The cipher works with 64-bit blocks and I'm having a tough time deciding how to partition the data so that its useable. In case your wondering the data will be coming from a file and I'm just going to pad it with zeroes until the nearest multiple of 64. Here's what I've been thinking about.

**Store an array of longs.**
With an array of longs I can traverse over each block in the fewest amount of steps. But, will the logical operations, like XOR, work properly? Also when I have to split the 64-bit into 32-bits should I convert to ints or just keep using longs? And then there is the sign to worry about, but I think I could use the Long class to fix that.

**Store an array of byte arrays.**
This was my initial idea, but I'm seeing the limitations now. I would have to work with 8 elements per array rather than just one with the array of longs. This might not even matter I don't know.

**BitSets.**
I saw these and thought they were the answer I've been looking for, but when I started using them I realized that they are not suited to the problem at hand and a lot of the methods don't actually do what I thought they would do.

I'm wondering how someone more experienced would do this. I think longs are the way to go, but I'm wondering if all the arithmetic will work. Am I on the right track or is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? It's very difficult to create a cipher that is really secure.

Comment: @UwePlonus It's just an exercise. And I'm not frightened by difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the most efficient *primitive* type for your cipher. So if you primarily use 64 bit instructions, please go for `long`. If you use primarity 32 bit instructions then `int` is probably the best type. I'll let you guess the types for 16 and 8 bit operations.

Note that you should not present this interface directly to the outside world. Instead you should use an interface based on byte arrays (just like, e.g. `Cipher`). You don't want to confront your users with a ton of grief with regards to big endian, signed/unsigned etc. Besides that, ciphers are usually defined for messages of a specific size in bits or bytes.

Certainly do not use `BitSet`. It's a horrible (unbounded) interface with many peculiarities. It is absolutely not fit for this kind of operations.

Comment: Almost but not entirely the same as the answer of Uwe I guess, but I was already typing.

Comment: Yeah, I learned a little bit about BitSet tonight. Horrible is a good word. I will take a look at the Cipher source and see what they're doing for some ideas.

Comment: Cipher is just an interface, implemented by a CipherSpi, which usually again forwards it to some kind of engine class. You are better off looking at e.g. the AES engines in Bouncy Castle, although I would not necessarily copy their interface or "documentation" mind you :) If you are feeling bold, look up the implementation of Sun/Oracle, it's GPL'ed, so why not.

Comment: Yeah, not copying. I just like to look at the source to see how somebody would do it the right way. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Probably the source code of com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher is best for 64 bit. Check out the openjdk project if you cannot find it, it *must* be in there.

Answer (score 2):

Use a data structure that fits your need the best.

If you never want to split you values then use `long`. If you need to split your data into two halves then use `int`.

If you need to have more control over your data you should go with `byte[]`. Because internal representation is not an issue for you (because you use Java) there is no need to use `byte[]` internally.

When it comes to communiction with other computers (e.g. via network socket or file) it is possible that the byte order is important. Then it would be better to use a `byte[]` as then you have better control over the byte order.

A `BitSet` is for other use cases and not feasible to be used in encryption.

Comment: I think you answered all of my questions. But @owlstead read between the lines. I agree with every point you made. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @shakabra You can always upvote one question and accept the other one. I guess you haven't upvoted yet as I already upvoted Uwe and it's still at 1...